# Thick table perimeter

Tags: tables

First off, I understand there are many threads on table styling etc. I am relatively new to Latex and am writing my thesis. I wish to use a consistent table format throughout.

Essentially, I'm trying to achieve a thicker border around the table. I currently have what's beneath.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|ll}
\cline{1-3}
\textbf{Postcode area} & \textbf{Postcode area name} & \textbf{Population} &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
S                      & Sheffield                   & 1358507             &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
M                      & Manchester                  & 1167402             &  &  \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This produces:

[image: tbl]

If any clearer, professional styles are known, please inform me!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have a look at the documentation of the [`booktabs` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to see what good table styling is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always wrap your `tabular`s in an `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\fboxrule=1.5pt\relax
\fboxsep=0pt\relax
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\cline{1-3}
\textbf{Postcode area} & \textbf{Postcode area name} & \textbf{Population}   \\ \cline{1-3}
S                      & Sheffield                   & 1358507               \\ \cline{1-3}
M                      & Manchester                  & 1167402                \\ \cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are also asking

> If any clearer, professional styles are known, please inform me!

I suggest to use the `booktabs` package and not use vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\textbf{Postcode area} & \textbf{Postcode area name} & \textbf{Population}\\
\midrule
S                      & Sheffield                   & 1358507\\ 
M                      & Manchester                  & 1167402\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ , http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html and https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf about how do make nice tables

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with the `boldline` package, from the `shipunov` bundle: it defines  `\hlineB` and `\clineB` commands and the `V` column delimiter. All accept a number as an argument, which represents the number of times the default rule width these thick rules will have. In addition, I loaded the `caption` package to have a sensible spacing between caption and table when caption is above table, and added some padding at the top of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{caption, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{V{3}l|l|lV{3}}
    \clineB{1-3}{3}
    \textbf{Postcode area} & \textbf{Postcode area name} & \textbf{Population} \\ \cline{1-3}
    S & Sheffield & 1358507 \\ \cline{1-3}
    M & Manchester & 1167402 \\ \clineB{1-3}{3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers, a design with `booktabs` (in the spirit of `booktabs`) is probably better, but if you actually want a thick border around your tabular, you can use `{NiceTabular}`. That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but also creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, row and columns. The, you can use those nodes with Tikz to draw whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[hvlines-except-borders]
    \RowStyle[bold]{}
    Postcode area & Postcode area name & Population \\ 
    S & Sheffield & 1358507 \\ 
    M & Manchester & 1167402 \\ 
    \CodeAfter
      \tikz \draw [very thick] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ;  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the first code]

For example, if you prefer rounded corners, you only have to add a key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
\caption{etc}
\label{my-label}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[hvlines-except-borders]
    \RowStyle[bold]{}
    Postcode area & Postcode area name & Population \\ 
    S & Sheffield & 1358507 \\ 
    M & Manchester & 1167402 \\ 
    \CodeAfter
      \tikz \draw [very thick, rounded corners] (1-|1) rectangle (last-|last) ;  
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]